# How to grant Calendar.ReadWrite.Shared permission to Azure app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, react-aad-msal

I'm trying to manage multiple outlook calendars using a single account as a proxy, so all other accounts share their personal calendar with this "master" account and within this one i can add, edit or delete events "for everyone".

The problem is that i can't get the account grant the Calendar.ReadWrite.Shared to the app, even though that in my app this permissions are configured as recommended.

Azure portal - app permissions:
[permissions of the app in azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj7TA.png)

msalconfig:
[msal configuration used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSxuK.png)

The "funny" thing is, with the account used to create the app in the first place everything works, but with any other account not.

I even created another app with the intended final account and nothing. This is the, incompplete permissions, resul:
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfSo7.png)

This is the desired result:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyVAL.png)

Comment: You are right @stanley-gong. I did exactly that and it worked!. Thanks!

Comment: WOW, glad to know it is helpful, I have summarized it as an answer, please accept it to close this question and it will also help other who have similar issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to make a proxy to modify calendars for all users, have you tried application-only Auth and grant `Calendars.ReadWrite` permission with `application` type to it? Based on this permission official comment: `Read and write calendars in all mailboxes` which seems to meet your requirement.